# Piping program output to less does not display beginning of the output

Tags: unix, pipe

I am trying to `make` a bunch of files in my directory, but the files are generating ~200 lines of errors, so they fly past my terminal screen too quickly and I have to scroll up to read them.

I'd like to pipe the output that displays on the screen to a pager that will let me read the errors starting at the beginning. But when I try

```
make | less
```

`less` does not display the beginning of the output - it displays the end of the output that's usually piped to the screen, and then tells me the output is 1 line long. When I try typing `Gg`, the only line on the screen is the line of the makefile that executed, and the regular screen output disappears.

Am I using `less` incorrectly? I haven't really ever used it before, and I'm having similar problems with something like, `sh myscript.sh | less` where it doesn't immediately display the beginning of the output file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The errors from `make` appear on the standard error stream (`stderr` in C), which is not redirected by normal pipes.  If you want to have it redirected to `less` as well, you need either `make |& less` (csh, etc.) or `make 2>&1 | less` (sh, bash, etc.).

Comment: Acccha, I thought it had something to do with that but I tried `make | less 2>& 1`. Had the redirect in the wrong place.

Comment: Could you please briefly explain what `2>&1` and `|&` do?

Answer (score 14):

Error output is sent to a slightly different place which isn't caught by normal pipelines, since you often want to see errors but not have them intermixed with data you're going to process further.  For things like this you use a redirection:

```
$ make 2>&1 | less
```

In `bash` and `zsh` (and `csh`/`tcsh`, which is where they borrowed it from) this can be shortened to

```
$ make |& less
```

With things like `make` which are prone to produce lots of errors I will want to inspect later, I generally capture the output to a file and then `less` that file later:

```
$ make |& tee make.log
$ less make.log
```

Comment: I tried using `make |& less` in bash, but I got a syntax error.

Comment: Hrm, looks like older `bash` doesn't have it; the system `bash` (3.2) on OSX doesn't accept it but a `bash` 4 from MacPorts does and so does the standard `bash` on Maverick.